# How to send a value from .aspx file to .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web

I have made a link on the webpage like

```
<a href="Products.aspx?id='something'">
```

Now this send id to a page `Products.aspx`
I want this value of id in the `Products.aspx.cs` file of the page so that I can write a query like

```
select * from Categories Where CategoryID = 'something'
```

Comment: the link is like
    <a href="products.aspx?id=something">

Comment: this just begs for sql injection. please use parametarized sql queries. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Guys I am trying to use.
Request.QueryString["id"]
but it gives red line under the Request. like is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following ,Below i mentioned get Querystring value in code behind.

```
        string Id = string.Empty;

        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            Id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        }

        var query = " select* from Categories Where CategoryID = '" + Id + "'";
```

Comment: I had just started web developement back then, and had no idea about these things but now this question is marked -2 and i cannot ask new questions because of this. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get id sent using `Query String` like below:

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
     string value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of way to pass id Form One Page to Another page Name

> Products.aspx Or Products.aspx.cs

Ill Explain Two way 
One is `Session` and Another is  `QueryString`.

Session Examle.............

> Session :  Assign Value of ID on Page A
>
> Session["id"]='something';
>
> Get Value On Page `Products.aspx`
>
> string Val=Session["id"].ToString();

Query String Examle.............

> QueryString:  Assign Value of ID on Page A
>
> string DymanicURL = string.Format("Products.aspx?id={0}", Val);
>          Response.Redirect(DymanicURL);
>
> Get Value On Page `Products.aspx`
>
> string x = Request.QueryString["id"];

For More Info http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring
and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can get the ID value in the targeted products cs page using following syntax

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["id"].tostring();
```

Comment: any library required for this Request?
because having a red line under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get query string values as passed in the way you describe using

```
var categoryId = Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]
```

You'll want to check that it's not null or empty before proceeding, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following

```
string Qvalue="";

if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null) {
     Qvalue = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); }
```

Your query should look likes this

```
select * from Categories Where CategoryID = '"+Qvalue+"'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to send id from one page to another CS page then you may use [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

```
class Person
{
    private string name;  // the name field
    public string Name    // the Name property
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On ASPX Page you may put value on properties like :

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "Joe";  // the set accessor is invoked here
OR
person.Name = txt_Name.Text;  // the set accessor is invoked here
```

after that get data On CS page.

```
System.Console.Write(person.Name);  // the get accessor is invoked here
OR
string Value= person.Name;  // the get accessor is invoked here
```